# load wordpress events into full calendar jquery

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery

I am trying to load my custom post type events into jquery plugin full calendar but nothing is working. I have made a php file with this code

```
include "wp-load.php";
global $wpdb;
header('Content-Type:application/json');
$events = array();
$result = new WP_Query('post_type=events&posts_per_page=-1');
foreach($result->posts as $post) {
$events[] = array(
'title'   => $post->post_title,
'start'   => '2018-03-12T20:00:00',

);
}
echo json_encode($events);
exit;
```

But its not loading anything

Comment: This is not the correct way to load WordPress. You should [move that code to a plugin, or a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). 
Also, I would replace the `include` statement by a `require`, so that the script breaks if it cannot find the file `wp-load.php`
And finally, you could add these two lines after the `require`: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`.

Answer (score 0):

Have reviewed your code but could not get what actually is wrong with the code.

Another possible solution is that, you can use third-party WordPress plugin **WP Full Calendar** and select your post type in the plugin settings. You can then use short-code to display the full calendar in any of your website page/post.

WP FullCalendar: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fullcalendar/

[image]